# emulator in vscode

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

when i try to run my code ( flutter ) in vscode and on an emualtor it gives me this error .
i can run my app in web or windows but not in emulator or android studio.

`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             74.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

`

i try to run in emulator but have no luck , runs fine in web

Answer (score 0):

There is no gradle version 7.1.2 available in gradle release.
You can use 7.1.1 or 7.2.

Gradle Release Official Doc : https://gradle.org/releases/

You need to define it in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` like this :

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

Comment: still no luck..

Comment: share android\build.gradle file in post.

Comment: shared . is it correct ?